Insert equation labels inside a `tikzcd` diagram in a way compatible with `cleveref`
This question is a follow-up to this one.
I want to annotate tikzcd diagrams with labels that can be referred to with \cref, placing the labels in arbitrary places in the diagram (usually, in the middle of the diagram). I also want to be able to change the name of the displayed label, just like the labels of equation environments can be changed using the \tag macro.
My minimal working example, inspired by the answer to the aforementioned question is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, quiver}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  eq node/.style={
    commutative diagrams/math mode=false, anchor=center},
  eq/.style={
    phantom,
    /tikz/every to/.append style={
      edge node={node[commutative diagrams/eq node]
        {\@eqnswtrue\make@display@tag\ltx@label{#1}}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNixbMCwwLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFswLDEsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzEsMSwiXFxidWxsZXQiXSxbMSwwLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFswLDIsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzEsMiwiXFxidWxsZXQiXSxbMCwxXSxbMSwyXSxbMCwzXSxbMywyXSxbMSw0XSxbNCw1XSxbMiw1XSxbOCw3LCIiLDEseyJzaG9ydGVuIjp7InNvdXJjZSI6MjAsInRhcmdldCI6MjB9LCJzdHlsZSI6eyJib2R5Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJub25lIn0sImhlYWQiOnsibmFtZSI6Im5vbmUifX19XSxbMTEsNywiIiwxLHsic2hvcnRlbiI6eyJzb3VyY2UiOjIwLCJ0YXJnZXQiOjIwfSwic3R5bGUiOnsiYm9keSI6eyJuYW1lIjoibm9uZSJ9LCJoZWFkIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJub25lIn19fV1d
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet
    \arrow[""{name=0, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow[""{name=1, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-2]
    \arrow[""{name=2, anchor=center, inner sep=0}, from=3-1, to=3-2]
    \arrow[draw=none, from=0, to=1, eq=eq:foo]
    \arrow[draw=none, from=2, to=1, eq=eq:bar]
\end{tikzcd}\]
Equations \ref{eq:foo} and \eqref{eq:bar}.
\end{document}

I thus have two questions.

How do I make this compatible with cleveref? As soon as I enable the package compilation fails with the error below (only one-letter labels seem to work):

Latexmk: ====Undefined refs and citations with line #s in .tex file:
  Label `e' multiply defined
  Label `e@cref' multiply defined
  Reference `eq:foo' on page 1 undefined on input line 29
  Reference `eq:bar' on page 1 undefined on input line 29


How do I change the equation numbers (1 and 2 in this case), to names I have chosen myself, just like it is usually possible to do so using the \tag command? Inserting it here doesn't seem to work.

Ideally I would also like to have a separate label counter for these tikzcd diagrams, so that I can customize how cleveref prints the references.
All in all, I would like to be able to write something like
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    ...
    \arrow[draw=none, from=0, to=1, eq=eq:foo, tag="\eta"]
    \arrow[draw=none, from=2, to=1, eq=eq:bar, tag="\mu"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\Cref{eq:foo,eq:bar}.

and get something that looks like 
where of course "eta" and "mu" should hyperlink to the corresponding squares.

I'm assuming here that AMSmath will always be loaded (otherwise \ltx@label will fail).
This defines a key number for use with \arrow which places a node with either a (CD) number or the provided tag in parentheses at a specific place.
If no at is given it uses the normal timer of the used \arrow path. The options at = matrix center (red) and at = diagram center (blue) are available, as well as just any normal placement, say at = {(2, 1)}.
If the label option is used (and its argment not empty) a \label will be used. It will use the \cref@label if cleveref is loaded, otherwise \ltx@label. (The normal \label will lead to problem because AMSmath is heavily managing it – for good reasons but here it gets in the way.)
The @@do* style is locally messing with the \thetikzcdequation macro (which defines usually how the counter is typeset) to also sneak the custom tag into the .aux file. This probably should be replaced by a proper definition of \@currentlabel …

Depending on your use case you might want to define a custom wrapper macro or at least custom styles for this because the repeated uses of \arrow can make this more cumbersome. But this will depend on how many and where you want to place these (CD) numbers.
Since it doesn't seem that they belong to an arrow, I'm setting path only to suppres any visual output of any path.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tikzcdequation}
\renewcommand*\thetikzcdequation{(\arabic{tikzcdequation})}
\newif\iftikzcd@eq@customtag
\tikzcdset{
  number/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/commutative diagrams/number}{
    /tikz/path only,normal tag,normal at,every number,#1,@do},
  number/every number/.code=,
  number/label/.initial=,
  number/tag/.code=\tikzcd@eq@customtagtrue\def\tikzcd@eq@tag{#1},
  number/normal tag/.code=
    \tikzcd@eq@customtagfalse\def\tikzcd@eq@tag{\thetikzcdequation},
  number/normal  at/.code=\def\tikzcd@eq@at{no at},
  number/at/matrix  center/.code=\def\tikzcd@eq@at{matrix center},
  number/at/diagram center/.code=\def\tikzcd@eq@at{diagram center},
  number/at/.code=% matrix center, diagram center or custom coordinate
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/commutative diagrams/number/at/#1/.@cmd}
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/number/at/#1/.@cmd}\pgfeov}
      {\def\tikzcd@eq@at{at={#1}}},
  number/@at no at/.code=, % should use timer of \arrow
  number/@at matrix  center/.style={
    commutative diagrams/number/@at at=(\tikzcdmatrixname.center)},
  number/@at diagram center/.style={
    commutative diagrams/number/@at at=(current bounding box.center)},
  number/@at at/.style={pos=,to path=\tikztonodes,nodes={at={#1}}},
  number/@do/.style={
    /tikz/every to/.append style/.expanded={
      commutative diagrams/number/@at \tikzcd@eq@at,
      edge node={
        node[commutative diagrams/eq node/.try,
             commutative diagrams/number/@@do\iftikzcd@eq@customtag*=%
            {\unexpanded\expandafter{\tikzcd@eq@tag}}\else=\fi
            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/number/label}}]{}}}},
  number/@@do/.style={
    node contents={
      \refstepcounter{tikzcdequation}\thetikzcdequation
      \IfBlankF{#1}{%
        \@ifpackageloaded{cleveref}{\cref@label{#1}}{\ltx@label{#1}}}}},
  number/@@do*/.style n args={2}{
    /utils/exec=\def\thetikzcdequation{(#1)}\addtocounter{tikzcdequation}{-1},
    commutative diagrams/number/@@do={#2}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{tikzcdequation}{CD equation}{CD equations}
\Crefname{tikzcdequation}{CD equation}{CD equations}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=3-2, bend left=90, min distance=2cm]
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-2, number={label=eq:foo, tag=$\eta$}]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=3-2, number={label=eq:bar, tag=$\mu$}]
    \arrow[green, number={at=matrix center}]
    \arrow[red, number={at=diagram center}]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Equations \ref{eq:foo}, \cref{eq:foo}.

Equations \ref{eq:bar}, \cref{eq:bar}.
\end{document}

Output


So, this doesn't use anything from the referenced Q&A and avoids AMSmath totally. I haven't tested how this works Inside some environments like align. Since these typeset things more than once we might need to protect against that.
